# Ruby on rails - create with wrong data type, it will change to 0 automatically

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Database**
group-name = varchar
group-status = int
user-name varchar
user-status = int

**Normal POST Case** (It is work perfectly.)
group-name = "Group Name"
group-status = 1
user-name "Name"
user-status = 0

**Special POST Case** (It will change the wrong data type value to 0.)
group-name = "Group Name"
group-status = "BBB"
user-name "Name"
user-status = "AAA"
It is because i want to get the "AAA" and "BBB" to handle the error by myself using rollback.

---

```
Group.transaction do
    group = Group.create(
        name: params["group-name"],
        status: params["group-status"]
    )
    user = User.create(
        name: params["user-name"],
        status: params["user-status"]
    )
end
```

Comment: Add a validation for the field, then Rails will not do the insert

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading this right, you'll just need to validate numericality in the relevant models. Read the docs for more info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality).

So add:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  validates :status, numericality: { only_integer: true, allow_nil: true }
  ...
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  validates :status, numericality: { only_integer: true, allow_nil: true }
  ...
end
```

This will provide an error if the data type is incorrect, which you can handle as you've discussed.

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions!

Comment: @kase - did this do the job for you?